# Why is MKMapSnapshotter not working in prepare function?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios-simulator, mapkit

I have a function that takes a snapshot from my MapView based on the coordinates of a MKPolygon.

```
 func takeSnapShot(){
    let mapSnapshotOptions = MKMapSnapshotOptions()
    let polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: self.coordinates, count: self.coordinates.count)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(polygon.boundingMapRect)
    mapSnapshotOptions.region = region

    mapSnapshotOptions.scale = UIScreen.main.scale

    mapSnapshotOptions.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)

    mapSnapshotOptions.showsBuildings = true
    mapSnapshotOptions.showsPointsOfInterest = true

    let snapShotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: mapSnapshotOptions)
    snapShotter.start{ (snapshot:MKMapSnapshot?, error:Error?) in
       self.snapshot = snapshot
    }
}
```

The code works fine if I call the function from `viewDidLoad()` or any other function. It won't work in my `prepare` function:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    guard let button = sender as? UIBarButtonItem, button === save_button else {
        os_log("The save button was not pressed, cancelling", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return
    }
    takeSnapShot()

}
```

Is there any restriction I missed?

Comment: I think that in the prepare function the ViewController is not loaded so that can be the issue, why you need that in the prepare, why not in the ViewDidAppear?

Comment: I want to navigate back to another ViewController but need to create an object. Thats what im doing in the prepare function

Comment: seems like the 'MKMapSnapshotter.start' is not called in this function, but I don't unterstand why not.

Comment: I think if your mapView is not loaded yet you can't take a snapshot from it

Comment: But it works if I call the function in viewDidLoad. So im sure that my MapView ist loaded. And I don't need a MapView if I don't want to